# I have two Github Accounts and the one I never use is pushing commits to my main account

Tags: git, github

As the title states I have two GitHub Accounts. One I created a long time ago Maurice333 and I haven't used in a long time, I believe that I initially created this account on my windows machine. The second one is m00se333 my "main" account, which I created on a MacBook.

Yesterday and today I was working on my windows machine and I believed that I was working under the guise of m00se333. But when I checked the repository I was working on just a few minutes ago I show no activity on my main account and all the work I did yesterday, save for the creation of a `README.md`, was pushed by the old Maurice333 account. I want the work that I'm doing to be pushed by a consistent user and I don't know how my older account got mixed up in this. I would like some help correcting this issue.

Here is some additional info:

`git config user.name` I get m00se333 - the username I want

`git config user.email` I get the email associated with my "old" account (Maurice333)

Is the discrepancy between username and email causing my pushes from my local machine to favor one over the other?

In the grand scheme of things it's not the biggest deal but I would like it fixed. I appreciate the anyone taking the time to read this and lend a hand.

Thanks.

Comment: Check maybe your ssh settings ? Maybe your default github.com ssh key is set under your Maurice333 account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here take two things play in action: You authenticate with your GitHub credentials so you can push data and you also can define in the config any other login which is used for public information like the commit details. This information can differ which is sometimes very handy.

If you want to change the history, to enforce that you just have one account in your history you could give a try to a tool called [blame someone else](https://github.com/jayphelps/git-blame-someone-else). This will allow you to rewrite the history of your git repository.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, but I figured it out. I just needed to change my `user.email` to match my main account.